# how to apply page size in display tag as per user request?

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I have created one drop down for pasize selection.

```
<s:select name="pageSize" cssClass="drop"
  list="#actResultLimitValue.lstEntities" listKey="code"
  listValue="value" onchange="document.forms[0].submit()">
```

And pageSize attribute is there in Actionclass. I used this variable in display  tag. Nothing happend. i am getting error.

```
<display:table id="data" name="lstEntities"  sort="list"  uid="row" class="main"
  pagesize="<%pageSize%>" export="true"
  requestURI="findPrtyByPrty.action">
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked well for below code,

```
<s:set name="selectedPageSize" value="pageSize" scope="request"/>
<display:table id="data" name="lstEntities"  sort="list"  uid="row" class="main"
        pagesize="${selectedPageSize}"  export="false"
        requestURI="findPrtyByPrty.action">
```

Answer (score 0):

Eh... I did just have this as a comment, but I'm pretty confident after staring at it for a while that it's the correct answer... so I'll put a real answer.

It looks like you're trying to get the pageSize from your scripting language... if it's jsp try

```
pagesize="<%=pageSize%>"
```

Though you say it's in the action class so... if you're trying to get it from struts2 try

```
pagesize="<s:property value="pageSize"/>"
```